# Не приходят заголовки в spring security

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-security, jwt

Сделал авторизацию с помощью JWT фильтра, когда работаю с POSTMANом, то все хорошо, но когда начинаю делать запросы из браузера, то все ломается. Ставил точки остановы в JWT фильтре и при запросе из браузера он не находит токен. + в браузере пишет: [image: + в браузере пишет]
Но допустим если я делаю этот эндпоинт permitAll(), то хэдер уже будет и я смогу сделать авторизацию(только зачем она нужна, если permitAll).

JS запрос:

```
let path = "http://localhost:8081/api/posts"
            let config = {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer_"+localStorage.access_token
                }
            }
            await axios.get(path, config).then(response=>{
                messages =  response.data
            })
```

Postman:

[image: Request из постмана]

Браузер:

[image: Request из браузера]

Конфигурация spring security:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT, REGISTRATION_ENDPOINT).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(ADMIN_ENDPOINT).hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(POST_ENDPOINT).hasRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо разрешить Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) запросы. Добавьте в класс конфигурации  spring security следующий бин:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config.applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло! Только ещё добавил http.cors().and()...