# Как устранить ошибку Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9099/rpc' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy?

Tags: java, angular, cors, http-server, авторизация

У меня есть

```
HttpServer server = com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
```

к которому я пытаюсь прикрутить BasicAuthenticator

```
HttpContext context = server.createContext("/rpc", new RpcHandler());
        context.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator("rpc") {
            @Override
            public boolean checkCredentials(String user, String pwd) {
                return user.equals("admin") && pwd.equals("password");
            }
        });
        server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        server.start();


также к нему хендлер:


class RpcHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpExchange.getRequestBody(), "utf-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                query.append(line);
            }

            JSONRPC2Response response;

            JSONRPC2Request request = null;
            try {
                if (query == null) {
                    throw new JSONRPC2ParseException(null);
                } else {
                    request = JSONRPC2Request.parse(query.toString());
                    if (request.getMethod().startsWith("update_metadata")) {
                        response = updateMetadata(request);
                    } else if (request.getMethod().equals("topics_lag_timestamp")) {
                        response = getTopicLagHandler(request);
                    } else {
                        response = new JSONRPC2Response(JSONRPC2Error.METHOD_NOT_FOUND, request.getID());
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONRPC2ParseException e) {
                response = new JSONRPC2Response(JSONRPC2Error.PARSE_ERROR, null);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                response = new JSONRPC2Response(JSONRPC2Error.INVALID_PARAMS, null);
            }

            httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST");
            httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

            OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();

            httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.toJSONString().length());
            outputStream.write(response.toJSONString().getBytes());

            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

При обращении через Postman с header

> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=

Все работает отлично.

Но при обращении из другого сервиса (фронт на Angular)

```
   @Component({
  selector: 'app-lag-timestamp-postgres',
  templateUrl: './lag-timestamp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lag-timestamp.component.css']
})
export class LagTimestampPGComponent implements OnInit {
  url = 'https://localhost:9099/rpc';
  response: any;
  lagTimestamps: LagsArray;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
      this.getLagTimestamp();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLagTimestamp();
  }

  getLagTimestamp() {
    const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ='};
    this.response = this.http.post(this.url, '{"method":"topics_lag_timestamp","id":"req-id-01","jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
      {headers})
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.response = response;
        this.lagTimestamps = Object.setPrototypeOf(this.response, Array<LagTimestampObject>());
        console.log(this.lagTimestamps);
      });
  }
}
```

я получаю ошибку:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9099/rpc' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Если убрать HttpContext и аутентификацию, все работает нормально.

Как устранить эту проблему? И где она вообще кроется, на стороне сервиса-фронта (Angular) или на стороне HttpServer?

Дополнение (заголовки запросов-ответов):
[image: OPTIONS]
[image: вPOST]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194737/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-spring-security/1194738#1194738

Comment: это решение для Spring. Также у меня указано             httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
Или я что-то упустил?

Comment: Откройте дебаггер в браузере кнопкой F12, вкладку Network и посмотрите какие хидеры уходят и приходят

Comment: добавил в описание вопроса

Comment: Проверяйтё `httpExchange.getRequestMethod()` и обрабатывайте OPTIONS запрос в соответствии с правилами CORS.

Comment: Пока что вы в ответ на OPTIONS-запросы кидаете JSONRPC2ParseException, потому вас и не пускает.

Answer (score 0):

По идее всё ок, возможно стоит потюнить запрос, например что-то вроде:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=');

fetch('http://localhost:8000/rpc', {
    credentials: 'include', // для передачи basic
    headers: headers,
    mode: "no-cors",
});
```

Comment: а как fetch прикручивать?

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский каким образом у вас сейчас запросы идут, axios?

Comment: HttpClient  this.response = this.http.post(this.url, '{"method":"topics_lag_timestamp","id":"req-id-01","jsonrpc":"2.0"}',
      { headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQ='}})
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.response = response;
        this.lagTimestamps = Object.setPrototypeOf(this.response, Array<LagTimestampObject>());
        console.log(this.lagTimestamps);
      });

Comment: да, но что такое this.http?

Comment: import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';     ...    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
      this.getLagTimestamp();
  }

Comment: внес более полное описание компонента в сам вопрос

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский c angular к сожалению не смогу помочь, но по сути вам нужно как-то добавить credentials: 'include', mode: "no-cors" параметры

Comment: Я вот думаю может это можно как-то пофиксить на стороне сервера? Через браузер или postman нет таких проблем.