# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, xmlhttprequest, cross-origin

Написал приложение на Angular(port 4200) и Spring Boot(port 8080). Теперь хочу залить на публичный сервак.
Когда запускаю приложение без tomcat из IDE, то такие ошибки пофиксил путем реализации интерфейса `Filter` в конфиге. А вот когда оно запущено на tomcat, то сыпятся те же ошибки после обращения к ресурсам:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/categories/all' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал добавлять разные фильтры в *tomcat/conf/**web.xml***. Ничего не менялось. Что сейчас есть:

**Configuration**(устанавливаю всем ответам в заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` : `http://localhost:4200`)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    Filter.super.destroy();
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", 
config.applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

**tomcat/conf/web.xml** (бесполезный)

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Директории webapp с web.xml в проекте нет. Зависимостей на tomcat нет. Буквально не знаю куда копать, то ли спрингу что то добавить, то ли томкату что то добавить, то ли и тому и другому) Вся надежда на вашу помощь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1194737/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-spring-security/1194738#1194738

Comment: @AlekseiGaile Я не использую Spring Security.

Comment: этот бин разрешает кросс-запросы, к секьюрети не относится.

Comment: @AlekseiGaile Всё куда интересней, этот бин оказывается у меня уже есть, почему то в вопросе не вставился.